# XeTeX in Linux doesn't work.

Tags: xetex, texworks, linux

I'm a newbie, and 
I'm trying to use `xetex` in  Fedora15.
I'm using TeXworks as my editor. 
but it throws back the error:

```
    /usr/bin/xetex: unrecognized option '-synctex=1'
This is XeTeXk, Version 3.141592-2.2-0.996 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cvinn.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  [a4paper,10pt]{article}
?
```

I really don't understand. Why is this error appearing?
is the `\documentclass` wrong?

Comment: This looks like you are compiling your document with `xetex` and not `xelatex`.  Try it with `xelatex` and see if it works.

Comment: @alan thanks for your reply.but when i compile with xelatex i get:
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
                                                  
No pages of output.
Transcript written on xelatex.log.' instead of a filename.
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!

Comment: @cyberscientist: That's another question. It means you should update your TeX distribution. Install latest TeX Live in TUG and retry.

Comment: @Leo: I have the latest live tex version. here is the yum output:
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Package texlive-2007-62.fc15.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: We hate to break it to you, but it's 2011 :-) and the latest TeXLive is 2010 (soon to be 2011). Your version is almost 4 years out of date (2007).  Check out this question: [How to install a vanilla TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/2693)

Comment: @Alan: thanks dude, After an update to 2010 version i still have :This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!

Comment: Did you install everything from scratch, or just parts?

Comment: I updated my reposetory and then used yum install command.Noy sure if that from the scratch or not but its the advice from [http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive#TeX_Live_2010_stable]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Fedora, but looking at that link, you may have installed the "basic" scheme, which doesn't fully install xelatex, possibly.  Or there's some issue with the Fedora packaging/installation. (But I don't know that for sure.)  You should revise your question with the new error and explain what you've done; perhaps there are some Fedora users here who can help. The general consensus here among Linux users seems to be that it is preferable to install your own version of TeXLive and avoid any of the pre-packaged ones.